# Extract words that starts with a certain character

Tags: angular, regex, typescript

I want display address contents start with example `DRACHMAN`. I try using `match()` but it not working as expected. This my demo [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-reactive-forms-pvhpv7)

**HTML**

```html
    <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #Form="ngForm">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="address">Address</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="name"
                   required
                   [(ngModel)]="data.address" name="address"
                   #name="ngModel"></textarea>
             </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    
        </form>
```

**Component**

```json
    data = {
        address: 'Bla..Bla..Bla..  421 E DRACHMAN  TUCSON AZ 5705-7598  USA'
      }
```

I want it display output like this image:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `match` function takes in a `regex`

From your description it looks like you need to match the word `DRACHMAN`. This we can match using `/DRACHMAN/`. You also need to match everything after that `(.)*`
Therefore we can finally merge

```javascript
  initialData = {
    address: "Bla..Bla..Bla..  421 E DRACHMAN  TUCSON AZ 5705-7598  USA"
  };
  data = {
    ...this.initialData,
    address: this.initialData.address.match(/DRACHMAN(.)*/)
  };
```

Have a look at [this fork](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-reactive-forms-knosyg)

Comment: Thank you so much brother...This is what I want

Comment: That is great! glad to help